# handle Querystring with jQuery or in APSX page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, query-string

I have the following querystring (where kvks is dynamic):

```
http://api.openkvk.nl/json/SELECT bedrijfsnaam FROM kvk WHERE kvks = 27312152 LIMIT 1;
```

If you execute this querystring, it will return json data.
What is the best approach to handle this? I tried it in this way, but nothing alerts

```
url.append("http://api.openkvk.nl/json/SELECT bedrijfsnaam FROM kvk WHERE kvks = ");
url.append(Dossierno);
url.append(" LIMIT 1");

$.get(url, function (data) {
            alert(data); });
```

Or should I handle this in a separate aspx page?

```
$.get('getaddress.aspx', { sDossierno : Dossierno} function (data) {
            alert(data); });
```

If yes, how can I send a querystring and return the json object on the getaddress aspx page?

Comment: It's a REALLY bad idea to pass around a plain text query in your querystring...Do a search for SQL Injection. Edit - Or is that some sort of external custom query API that handles the security aspect itself? External or not, still looks really bad.

Comment: in short, i will execute http://api.openkvk.nl/json/delete from kvk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not query string that you have. It's part of the uri and ASP.NET won't probably allow it. You may try the following:

```
$.get( 
    'http://api.openkvk.nl/json', 
    { q: 'SELECT bedrijfsnaam FROM kvk WHERE kvks = ' + Dossierno + ' LIMIT 1' }, 
    function (data) {
        alert(data); 
    }
);
```

where the corresponding server side script will read the `q` query string parameter.

Also I hope you are aware of the implications in terms of security of having a server side script which accepts what seems to be a SQL query and executes it against a relational database. And last but not least don't forget about the [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and make sure that this script is hosted on `http://api.openkvk.nl` if you intend to send AJAX requests to it.

Answer (score 1):

- Do not pass entire SQL Queries in query strings, as it allows for malicious code to reach your database.
- string variables do not have an append method, so check if that really works as expected (alert the url to see if it is what you expect it to be)
- You are not allowed to make requests from a different domain (*if you page is not at api.openkvk.nl*), only JSONP is allowed cross-domain. Check [same-origin-policy](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSame_origin_policy&ei=cslbTamzA8Gt8gPozNmVAg&usg=AFQjCNHVFZYpkC1JSDNgda021fYJ8pRuDQ).